# writing javascript without load and .ready functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to write javascript code without using `load()` function and jquery's `.ready()` to execute javascript code? If yes then how can we do this? Please provide some tutorial links for this kind of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes but why would you want to? Put your scripts at the bottom before the closing `</body>` tag and you won't need to use `document.ready()`.

Links:

- http://encosia.com/dont-let-jquerys-document-ready-slow-you-down/
- [Can I avoid putting $(document).ready() calls in each JavaScript file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8364498/can-i-avoid-putting-document-ready-calls-in-each-javascript-file)
- [jQuery: Why use document.ready if external JS at bottom of page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1438883/jquery-why-use-document-ready-if-external-js-at-bottom-of-page)

Comment: Do I need to use load function while following this way?

Comment: depends what you're doing with your code... Can I ask why you want to take this route?

Comment: I want to call functions which are inside another js file. when use clicks on link or button then those functions will fire. Currently I am using `.ready()` function where I am getting all the click events from user. So because of this I am using a lot of code in .read() function.